# Proving the Validity of a Sequent containing "Contradicting Assumptions" (Logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I was doing some exercises in my course book when I came across a weird question. I was asked to prove the validity of the following sequent:

$ \vdash \neg p \to (p \to (p \to q)) $

I'm having trouble understanding the given solution of that exercise:
[image]

Specifically, why is the first $p$ assumption not "rejected" as a contradiction, while the second $p$ assumption is?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do get a contradiction in line $4$.

Comment: Yes indeed :) however what I didn't understand is why line 2 wasn't followed up with a contradiction immediately!

Comment: No particular reason. The author seems to have wanted to demonstrate explicitly deriving $p\to q$ using deduction, which is *not wrong*, but there was no *need* to. Once you have a contradition *anything* follows, including compound predicates. So you *may* as well just note the contradiction immediately after the second assumption, then invoke the principle of explosion before discharging the contradictory assumptions. $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{1.~~\neg p}{\fitch{2.~~p}{3.~~\bot\\4.~~p\to q}\\5.~~p\to(p\to q)}\\6.~~\neg p\to (p\to(p\to q))}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* write the very same proof but instead justify line 4 as "$\neg$e 2,1" -- and that would be equally valid. The author of the proof only just made a random choice of which of the two $p$ assumptions to appeal to. (Both of the assumptions have to *be there* in order to get two "$p\to$" in the eventual conclusion, but which of them is used for $\neg$e is not important).

Indeed you could then *also* have chosen to apply the $\neg$e rule *before* starting the innermost box. That would produce yet a different, still valid, proof.

---

It also sounds like you're slightly misunderstanding the purpose of the $\neg$e rule. It is not there to "reject" a *particular* assumption -- indeed its premises need not be assumptions at all; they could be concluded using other rules along the way.

What $\neg$e tells you is just that the totality of *all* the assumptions you have in play at that point in the proof is contradictory. The proof system doesn't really care to track *which* of your possibly many assumptions contradict each other; it just concludes that there is a contradiction *somewhere*.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm beginning to understand. So I can think of the negation-elimination rule as something i _can_ use, not something I _must_ use? Like, just because I assume neg(p) and then assume p, I am not **obligated** to apply the negation-elimination rule and achieve a contradiction?

Comment: @SimonSirak: Correct -- and that is so for _all_ of the rules. If you reach the conclusion you want at the end of the proof and you have only used _allowed_ rules, then the proof is good, not matter that there were other rules you _could_ have used.

Comment: Your book may be saying something like "you must use the $\to$i rule when you're trying to prove $\mathit{blah}\to\mathit{blah}$" -- but that's a different kind of "must", one that just means "this happens to be the only rule that makes progress for you". However, in the stricter sense of "it will make your proof invalid not to do this", there is never a "must" for any rule.

Comment: that's such an eye opener :D similarly, I should be able to assume the same thing multiple times in a nested manner as done in the solution (and maybe even in a non-nested manner??) , and then apply different rules to the different branches?

Comment: Nevermind the "non-nested"-parenthesis, the same assumption is done several times in the same "box-level (only the current box level, not children)" would just be dumb! Unless you want to show your failed attempts or something :p

Comment: @SimonSirak: It is not completely clear to me what you're proposing, but it sounds like, "yes you can". (Note that it is almost always a _good idea_ to use $\neg$e as early as you can, because no matter what you were aiming to reach at the end of the current box, you can then get there in one more step by $\neg$e).

Comment: [I meant, of course: "... get there in one more step by $\bot$e"].